# Vue with bootstrap-vue : prevent more than one expanded list-element at all times in list (v-for)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

i'm using vue with bootstrap-vue and the feature of b-collapse, and in this case it's used in v-for (lists)..

it's working well, except that i cannot figure out how to automagically close the expanded list-elements when a new list-element is clicked for expanding..

**So my question is :**

How can i close the expanded ones, when i click a new list-element for expanding ?

Remark : I'm generating the v-b-toggle="" with unique values like this :

```
<i v-b-toggle="'collapse' + key + index"
```

**Here is my code :**

```
<div v-for="(item, key, index) in nluData">
   <div v-for="(item, key, index) in nluData">
       <div class="alert alert-warning">
           <i v-b-toggle="'collapse' + key + index">&nbsp;</i>
       </div>

   <b-collapse :id="'collapse' + key + index">
       <b-card style="background-color:#f0f8ff; margin-right:-30px;">
           ....
       </b-card>
   </b-collapse>
</div>
```

**UPDATE AFTER @sklingler93 SUGGESTION :**

Changed to the following :

```
<i @click="expanded=key">&nbsp;</i>
<b-collapse :id="'collapse' + key + index" visible="key == expanded">
```

Vue data property :

```
 export default {
data() {
      return {
          expanded: 0
          }
      }
```

I tried different types on expanded (string, boolean, int)
This ended up with everything expanded and the following warning either how :

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "visible". Expected Boolean, got String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b-collapse` has a visible property that you can set. So if you declare a variable in your `data` to keep track of which `b-collapse` is expanded, you can use that:

```html
<div v-for="(item, key, index) in nluData">
   <div v-for="(item, key, index) in nluData">
       <div class="alert alert-warning">
           <i @click="expanded=key">&nbsp;</i>
       </div>

   <b-collapse :visible="key === expanded">
       <b-card style="background-color:#f0f8ff; margin-right:-30px;">
           ....
       </b-card>
   </b-collapse>
   </div>
</div>
```